# Why do my fonts render differently when page is loaded via link?

Tags: html, css, webfonts

I'm experiencing a weird issue on a site when it is loaded via a link.

Here are the two different instances:

1. Load http://www.visioncreativegroup.com.au via the URL bar. Fonts load as expected (medium weight).
2. Visit http://www.wpagroup.com.au and click the 'website by vision' link in the footer. The fonts are much bolder as seen in [this screenshot](http://cl.ly/image/2s143D33193t).

The fonts are being loaded using @font-face.

Has anyone stumbled across a similar problem before? What could be causing this?

Comment: Both the same for me in Chrome.

Comment: Mac or PC? I can't recreate the issue on my computer either (Safari on Mac OS X), but it was reported in Chrome.

Comment: Ok, cheers. I think it was reported in Chrome on Mac!

Comment: Both pages are identical for me in Firefox, Chrome and Safari under OSX. Note that the font renders bolder for me in Firefox, and less bold in Chrome. Suspect your issue is rendering differently in different browsers, not rendering differently in the same browser based on url/link-click context.

Comment: Identical for me on Chrome 20 on PC.

Comment: Identical for Chrome on Mac OS X. Maybe suggest that whoever took the screenshot clear their cache.

Comment: You should probably verify that a problem is reproducible (or actually exists) first before looking to solve it.

Comment: If you haven't been able to reproduce this yourself, you shouldn't be posting a question about it on Stack Overflow. The problem is almost certainly with the person reporting the bug, and not the symptoms you've described which are pretty nonsensical.

Comment: They look the same to me. Iceweasel on Debian Wheezy.

Comment: @Tim My advice remains correct: If you are unable to reproduce a problem yourself, you shouldn't be posting it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this...

```
.semi {
    font-family: 'AauxNext-SemiBold',sans-serif;
    font-weight: normal;
}
```

It shows up bold in firefox on mac like it did in the screenshot. If you add font-weight: normal; it is no longer bold. I think firefox and others render the font differently, possibly something to do with it being semiBold?

Comment: I wouldn't say that it's a bug, it's just one of those anomalies that make cross-browser testing so necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try pixels instead of percentage.

```
font-size:xxpx;  instead of percentage.
```

i am not sure,may it help you.